# ESPAsyncWebServer code not compiling

Tags: esp8266, library

## Error messages

```
    Arduino: 1.8.14 Hourly Build 2020/12/15 11:33 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:62:18: error: 'HTTP_GET' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       62 |   HTTP_GET     = 0b00000001,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:29: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_GET'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                             ^~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:63:18: error: 'HTTP_POST' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       63 |   HTTP_POST    = 0b00000010,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:50: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_POST'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:64:18: error: 'HTTP_DELETE' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       64 |   HTTP_DELETE  = 0b00000100,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:83: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_DELETE'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:65:18: error: 'HTTP_PUT' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       65 |   HTTP_PUT     = 0b00001000,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:61: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_PUT'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                                                             ^~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:66:18: error: 'HTTP_PATCH' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       66 |   HTTP_PATCH   = 0b00010000,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:71: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_PATCH'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:67:18: error: 'HTTP_HEAD' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       67 |   HTTP_HEAD    = 0b00100000,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:39: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_HEAD'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                                       ^~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:68:18: error: 'HTTP_OPTIONS' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       68 |   HTTP_OPTIONS = 0b01000000,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:96: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_OPTIONS'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:4:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:69:18: error: 'HTTP_ANY' conflicts with a previous declaration
    
       69 |   HTTP_ANY     = 0b01111111,
    
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
    
    In file included from C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\iot_project_4\iot_project_4.ino:2:
    
    C:\Users\JUNAID\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:47:19: note: previous declaration 'HTTPMethod HTTP_ANY'
    
       47 | enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
    
          |                   ^~~~~~~~
    
    Multiple libraries were found for "ESPAsyncTCP.h"
    
     Used: C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncTCP
    
     Not used: C:\Users\JUNAID\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncTCP-master
    
    exit status 1
    
    Error compiling for board Generic ESP8266 Module.
    
    
    
    This report would have more information with
    "Show verbose output during compilation"
    option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

## Code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
int Wifiled = 15;
  
ESP8266WebServer esp(80);

String HTML = "";
       
String FORM = "testing the second website";




void setup() 
{         
       HTML +="<html>";
       HTML +=  "<head>";
       HTML +=    "<title>MY SMART HOME</title>"; 
       HTML +="<style>";
       HTML +="body {background-color:#92e8e2;}";
       HTML +="#wrapper {background-color:#ebf5f4;width:93%;min-height:700px;margin:auto;barder:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}";
       HTML +="</style>";       
       
       HTML +=  "</head>";
       HTML +=  "<body>";
       HTML +=  "<div id='wrapper'>";    
       HTML +=    "<h3>WELCOME TO MY SMART SENSOR DATA</h3>";
       HTML +=    "<h2>PH SENSOR DATA   </h2>";
       HTML +=    "Serial.monitor";
       HTML +=    "<h2>EC SENSOR DATA </h2>";
       HTML +=  "</div >"; 
       HTML +=  "</body>";    
       HTML +="</html>";   
    pinMode(Wifiled,OUTPUT);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin("LAPTOP","123456789");
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
          Serial.print(".");
          digitalWrite(Wifiled,HIGH);
          delay(250);
          digitalWrite(Wifiled,LOW);
          delay(250);          
    }
        digitalWrite(Wifiled,HIGH);
        Serial.println("wifi connected");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());



        esp.on("/",sendHtml);
        esp.on("/process",sendform);
        esp.begin();
}
void sendform()
{
  esp.send(200,"text/html;",FORM);
}

void sendHtml()
{
  esp.send(200,"text/html;",HTML);
  
}

void loop() 
{
   esp.handleClient();
   delay(200);
   char buffer[20]="";
   if(Serial.available()>0){
  //  char data=Serial.read();
   Serial.readBytesUntil('\n',buffer,20);
   Serial.println(buffer);
   }
}
```

Comment: ESP8266WebServer conflicts with ESPAsyncWebServer. Both cannot be used in the same program. Your code does not seem to use make use ESPAsyncWebServer or its features, so you could remove the lines `#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>` and `#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>` from your code.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 1):

You've included <ESP8266WebServer.h> and <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>, it's one or the other, you can't have both. Hence you're getting error: 'HTTP_GET' conflicts with a previous declaration